# Need code for Inverse Error Function

Tags: delphi, math, pascal

Does anyone know where I could find code for the "Inverse Error Function?" Freepascal/Delphi would be preferable but C/C++ would be fine too.

The TMath/DMath library did not have it :(

Comment: do you mean inverse erf?

Comment: @soandosDavid Yup thats what I'm talking about

Comment: If you can find fortran code convert it to c with f2c -a . If you can find c code great. Compile the c with bcc32 and link with $L that's how I always do it!

Comment: This is a really nifty piece of math. If you find an implementation, I'll make sure it gets added to JEDI Math. It's planned for JEDI Math library in the future, but it looks like it's not in there yet!

Comment: Possibly useful information at [the Wolfram Functions site](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/InverseErf/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an implementation of `erfinv()`. Note that for it to work well, you also need a good implementation of `erf()`.

```
function erfinv(const y: Double): Double;

//rational approx coefficients
const
  a: array [0..3] of Double = ( 0.886226899, -1.645349621,  0.914624893, -0.140543331);
  b: array [0..3] of Double = (-2.118377725,  1.442710462, -0.329097515,  0.012229801);
  c: array [0..3] of Double = (-1.970840454, -1.624906493,  3.429567803,  1.641345311);
  d: array [0..1] of Double = ( 3.543889200,  1.637067800);

const
  y0 = 0.7;

var
  x, z: Double;

begin
  if not InRange(y, -1.0, 1.0) then begin
    raise EInvalidArgument.Create('erfinv(y) argument out of range');
  end;

  if abs(y)=1.0 then begin
    x := -y*Ln(0.0);
  end else if y<-y0 then begin
    z := sqrt(-Ln((1.0+y)/2.0));
    x := -(((c[3]*z+c[2])*z+c[1])*z+c[0])/((d[1]*z+d[0])*z+1.0);
  end else begin
    if y<y0 then begin
      z := y*y;
      x := y*(((a[3]*z+a[2])*z+a[1])*z+a[0])/((((b[3]*z+b[3])*z+b[1])*z+b[0])*z+1.0);
    end else begin
      z := sqrt(-Ln((1.0-y)/2.0));
      x := (((c[3]*z+c[2])*z+c[1])*z+c[0])/((d[1]*z+d[0])*z+1.0);
    end;
    //polish x to full accuracy
    x := x - (erf(x) - y) / (2.0/sqrt(pi) * exp(-x*x));
    x := x - (erf(x) - y) / (2.0/sqrt(pi) * exp(-x*x));
  end;

  Result := x;
end;
```

If you haven't got an implementation of `erf()` then you can try this one converted to Pascal from Numerical Recipes.  It's not accurate to double precision though.

```
function erfc(const x: Double): Double;
var
  t,z,ans: Double;
begin
  z := abs(x);
  t := 1.0/(1.0+0.5*z);
  ans := t*exp(-z*z-1.26551223+t*(1.00002368+t*(0.37409196+t*(0.09678418+
    t*(-0.18628806+t*(0.27886807+t*(-1.13520398+t*(1.48851587+
    t*(-0.82215223+t*0.17087277)))))))));
  if x>=0.0 then begin
    Result := ans;
  end else begin
    Result := 2.0-ans;
  end;
end;

function erf(const x: Double): Double;
begin
  Result := 1.0-erfc(x);
end;
```

Comment: Excellent. I think the implementation in the Pascal for Scientists for erf is better than the erf here.

Comment: @Warren Not according to my tests it isn't. So far as I can tell that one is rubbish for x near to 0 (IIRC). If I were doing this, I would translate the code from Numerical Recipes and get something accurate to double precision.

Comment: Oops--  the fortran code I linked to claims  at least 18 digits of precision.  Looks like the Jedi math library needs lots of work.

Comment: @Mike Thanks. Out of interest, do you have a good `erf()` or are you using the one I give above from NR?  Do you have a copy of NR?  If not you should get one.

Comment: For the knowledgable: I'd be interested in a routine with a free license (BSD) btw, NR's example code has a license that prevents distribution of sourcecode. Doesn't have to be in Pascal.

Comment: Source for the first algorithm please?

Comment: @Sh3ljohn What do you mean?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Haha, sorry I never noticed that this was ambiguous in English :) Do you have a _reference_ for the first algorithm? Is it adapted from an existing library, or is it your own?

Comment: @Sh3ljohn You know, I've no idea where it came from now. It's lame that I did not say so at the time. Sorry! If I was wanting to do this myself I think I'd find a good Fortran implementation on Netlib, convert to C with `f2c -a`, and link with `$LINK`.

Answer (score 2):

Pascal Programs for Scientists and Engineers has the gaussian Error function (erf) and its complement erfc=(1-errf), but not the Inverse of the Error function.  Obviously, you don't just take 1/ErrF.  The inverse means x = erfinv(y) satisfies y = erf(x).

http://infohost.nmt.edu/~armiller/pascal.htm

Error function and its complement, are shown in this listing.

Again, the definition of Error Function Complement is `1-ErrF`, not `ErrF^-1`, but this has got to be getting you close:

http://infohost.nmt.edu/~es421/pascal/list11-3.pas

I found this interesting implementation (language unknown, I'm guessing it's matlab). maybe it and its coefficients can help you:

http://w3eos.whoi.edu/12.747/mfiles/lect07/erfinv.m

Another PDF here:
http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/~gilesm/files/gems_erfinv.pdf

Relevant snippet:

Table 1: Pseudo-code to compute y = erfinv(x) , with p1(t)..p6(t) representing
a 1st through 6th polynomial function of t :

```
a = |x|        
if a > 0.9375 then
t = sqrt( log(a) )
y = p1(t) / p2(t)
else if a > 0.75 then
y = p3(a) / p4(a)
else
y = p5(a) / p6(a)
end if
if x < 0 then
y = −y
end if
```

Apparently the library code functions by approximation, it's less work.  Sometimes the approximations are to less than 6 decimal places accuracy, I read.

**Fortran code** that many people use for a reference, is [here](http://www.netlib.org/specfun/erf), it cites  ["Rational Chebyshev approximations for the error function](http://www.jstor.org/pss/2004390)" by W. J. Cody, Math. Comp., 1969, PP. 631-638.:

Comment: erf and its complement come with Free Pascal btw, unit "spe", speerf and speefc. Iirc their code is based on Algol code from the (German) Handbuch der Automatik.

Comment: Can you post the snippet? That would be a nice contrib.

Comment: I didn't initially since it isn't the inverse. But anyway, see below

Answer (score 1):

The [math](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseErf.html) is pretty complex, but there's a decent approximation described [here](http://homepages.physik.uni-muenchen.de/~Winitzki/erf-approx.pdf) (warning: PDF) that includes Maple code.  Unfortunately it involves a "solve for x" step that might make it useless to you.

Answer (score 1):

Boost seems to have it as [error_inv](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/special/sf_erf/error_inv.html) so look at the code.

Comment: Great, thanks. It might be a bit clunky exporting this to a dll, but I guess i'll figure it out.

Comment: You could also look at the Python extension for SciPy, which is Pure C code.  http://www.rexx.com/~dkuhlman/scipy_course_01.html

Answer (score 1):

I've used this, which I believe is reasonably accurate and quick (usually 2 iterations of the loop), but of course caveat emptor. NormalX assumes that 0<=Q<=1, and would likely give silly answers if that assumption doesn't hold.

```
/* return P(N>X) for normal N */
double  NormalQ( double x)
{   return 0.5*erfc( x/sqrt(2.0));
}

#define NORX_C0   2.8650422353e+00
#define NORX_C1   3.3271545598e+00
#define NORX_C2   2.7147548996e-01
#define NORX_D1   2.8716448975e+00
#define NORX_D2   1.1690926940e+00
#define NORX_D3   4.7994444496e-02
/* return X such that P(N>X) = Q for normal N */
double  NormalX( double Q)  
{
double  eps = 1e-12;
int signum = Q < 0.5;
double  QF = signum ? Q : (1.0-Q);
double  T = sqrt( -2.0*log(QF));
double  X = T - ((NORX_C2*T + NORX_C1)*T + NORX_C0)
                    /(((NORX_D3*T + NORX_D2)*T + NORX_D1)*T + 1.0);
double  SPI2 = sqrt( 2.0 * M_PI);
int i;
    /* newton's method */
    for( i=0; i<10; ++i)
    {
    double  dX  = (NormalQ(X) - QF)*exp(0.5*X*X)*SPI2;
            X += dX;
            if ( fabs( dX) < eps)   
            {   break;
            }
    }
    return signum ? X : -X;
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, your NormalX is designed to calculate the same thing as errfinv in various bits of math-software?

Comment: (oops) erfinv(y) = NormalX( 0.5*(1.0-y))/sqrt(2.0);

Comment: It would be better if errfinv() defined as above was in the code sample.

Answer (score 0):

```
function erf(const x: extended): extended;
var
  n: integer;
  z: extended;
begin
  Result := x;
  z := x;
  n := 0;

  repeat
    inc(n);
    z := -z * x * x * (2 * n - 1) / ((2 * n + 1) * n);
    Result := Result + z;
  until abs(z) < 1E-20;

  Result := Result * 2 / sqrt(pi);
end;

function erfinv(const x: extended): extended;
var
  n: integer;
  z: extended;
begin
  Result := 0;
  n := 0;

  repeat
    inc(n);
    z := (erf(Result) - x) * sqrt(pi) / (2 * exp(-Result * Result));
    Result := Result - z;
  until (n = 100) or (abs(z) < 1E-20);

  if abs(z) < 1E-20 then
    n := -20
  else
    n := Floor(Log10(abs(z))) + 1;

  Result := RoundTo(Result, n);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have from spe. To me it looks like they tried to speed it up by dragging all functions into one big polynomal. Keep in mind this is code from the 386 era

```
// Extract from package Numlib in the Free Pascal sources (http://www.freepascal.org)
// LGPL-with-static-linking-exception, see original source for exact license.
// Note this is usually compiled in TP mode, not in Delphi mode.

Const highestElement = 20000000;

Type ArbFloat = double;  // can be extended too.
     ArbInt   = Longint;
     arfloat0   = array[0..highestelement] of ArbFloat;

function spesgn(x: ArbFloat): ArbInt;

begin
  if x<0
  then
    spesgn:=-1
  else
    if x=0
    then
      spesgn:=0
    else
      spesgn:=1
end; {spesgn}

function spepol(x: ArbFloat; var a: ArbFloat; n: ArbInt): ArbFloat;
var   pa : ^arfloat0;
       i : ArbInt;
    polx : ArbFloat;
begin
  pa:=@a;
  polx:=0;
  for i:=n downto 0 do
    polx:=polx*x+pa^[i];
  spepol:=polx
end {spepol};

function speerf(x : ArbFloat) : ArbFloat;
const

        xup = 6.25;
     sqrtpi = 1.7724538509055160;
     c : array[1..18] of ArbFloat =
     ( 1.9449071068178803e0,  4.20186582324414e-2, -1.86866103976769e-2,
       5.1281061839107e-3,   -1.0683107461726e-3,   1.744737872522e-4,
      -2.15642065714e-5,      1.7282657974e-6,     -2.00479241e-8,
      -1.64782105e-8,         2.0008475e-9,         2.57716e-11,
      -3.06343e-11,           1.9158e-12,           3.703e-13,
      -5.43e-14,             -4.0e-15,              1.2e-15);

     d : array[1..17] of ArbFloat =
     ( 1.4831105640848036e0, -3.010710733865950e-1, 6.89948306898316e-2,
      -1.39162712647222e-2,   2.4207995224335e-3,  -3.658639685849e-4,
       4.86209844323e-5,     -5.7492565580e-6,      6.113243578e-7,
      -5.89910153e-8,         5.2070091e-9,        -4.232976e-10,
       3.18811e-11,          -2.2361e-12,           1.467e-13,
      -9.0e-15,               5.0e-16);

  var t, s, s1, s2, x2: ArbFloat;
         bovc, bovd, j: ArbInt;
begin
  bovc:=sizeof(c) div sizeof(ArbFloat);
  bovd:=sizeof(d) div sizeof(ArbFloat);
  t:=abs(x);
  if t <= 2
  then
    begin
      x2:=sqr(x)-2;
      s1:=d[bovd]; s2:=0; j:=bovd-1;
      s:=x2*s1-s2+d[j];
      while j > 1 do
        begin
          s2:=s1; s1:=s; j:=j-1;
          s:=x2*s1-s2+d[j]
        end;
      speerf:=(s-s2)*x/2
    end
  else
    if t < xup
    then
      begin
        x2:=2-20/(t+3);
        s1:=c[bovc]; s2:=0; j:=bovc-1;
        s:=x2*s1-s2+c[j];
        while j > 1 do
          begin
            s2:=s1; s1:=s; j:=j-1;
            s:=x2*s1-s2+c[j]
          end;
        x2:=((s-s2)/(2*t))*exp(-sqr(x))/sqrtpi;
        speerf:=(1-x2)*spesgn(x)
      end
    else
      speerf:=spesgn(x)
end;  {speerf}

function spemax(a, b: ArbFloat): ArbFloat;
begin
  if a>b
  then
    spemax:=a
  else
    spemax:=b
end; {spemax}

function speefc(x : ArbFloat) : ArbFloat;
const

   xlow = -6.25;
  xhigh = 27.28;
      c : array[0..22] of ArbFloat =
      ( 1.455897212750385e-1, -2.734219314954260e-1,
        2.260080669166197e-1, -1.635718955239687e-1,
        1.026043120322792e-1, -5.480232669380236e-2,
        2.414322397093253e-2, -8.220621168415435e-3,
        1.802962431316418e-3, -2.553523453642242e-5,
       -1.524627476123466e-4,  4.789838226695987e-5,
        3.584014089915968e-6, -6.182369348098529e-6,
        7.478317101785790e-7,  6.575825478226343e-7,
       -1.822565715362025e-7, -7.043998994397452e-8,
        3.026547320064576e-8,  7.532536116142436e-9,
       -4.066088879757269e-9, -5.718639670776992e-10,
        3.328130055126039e-10);

  var t, s : ArbFloat;
begin
  if x <= xlow
  then
    speefc:=2
  else
  if x >= xhigh
  then
    speefc:=0
  else
    begin
      t:=1-7.5/(abs(x)+3.75);
      s:=exp(-x*x)*spepol(t, c[0], sizeof(c) div sizeof(ArbFloat) - 1);
      if x < 0
      then
        speefc:=2-s
      else
        speefc:=s
    end
end {speefc};
```